# How to tell what library logged an Error

Tags: java, logging, libraries

I'm getting the following in my console.  It's not coming from my code.  I've placed several libraries such as WebLogic, sun, javax, in my step filters.  Is there a way to tell which library generated this message?  I don't really want to step through all of the library classes that I'm using to try to find this.

```
[Fatal Error] :1:80: The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</body>".
```

Comment: What logging framework do they use?

Comment: You might want to use a search tool that can search the binary jar/class files of the library for the error string (probably without the "body" but, since that seems specific to your context).

Comment: @SirRichie, I don't know.  They might not all be using the same one either.  I don't think it's Log4J, which is what we're using.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I typically first reach for Google. These days most error messages have been posted by someone somewhere, although you have to ensure you strip your specifics (in this case the "body" sounds pretty specific) out of it.

If Google doesn't help or just takes too long, I typically end up running a binary search tool over my lib directory. The results aren't pretty. But once I know which jar contains the message, I can zoom into a prettier format for the details.